MTU of network device is changed periodically, can anyone help me to fix it?
here is the situation, I have a physical machine that installed uos operation system. For its eth1 interface, I need the mtu is 1750.
Unfortunately, the mtu is changed to 1500 periodically a moment after its ipv6 link local address disappears. Then, after few minutes, the link local address is configured and the mtu recover to 1750.
The machine is new and only installs uos and configure the network.
no cronjob, no other business is running on it.
Is there a way to locate who is it that change my nic's mtu?
here's eth1's configuration, file /etc/NetworkManager/system-connection/eth1.nmconnection:
[ethernet]
mtu=1750

[connection]
id=eth1
uuid=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx # this is a example value
type=ethernet
interface-name=eth1

FYI: eth1 is not use by physical machine, but is used by libvirt to create sriov interface, which is used by virtual machine on the physical machine. So there is no other ipv4/ipv6 configuration on eth1.
I have checked dmesg and network log and found nothing.
I need the mtu is fixed and set to 1750 permanently.
